# To Compare two my sql tables with 4 constraints and save the matched results in a new table

Tags: mysql, database

I want to compare 2 my sql tables with 4 constraints such as firstname,lastname,dob and address.If some records match i want to save it in the new table.

I compared 2 tables with 1 constraint using this query

```
  SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.dob IN (SELECT t2.dob from t2)
```

Is there any query to do this job?Any Help will be appreciated.

```
Table 1 

First Name  Varchar
Last  Name  Varchar
Dob         Date
Address     varchar
Email       Varchar
City        Varchar
Country     Varchar


Table2

First Name  Varchar
Last  Name  Varchar
Dob         Date
Address     varchar
```

If records matches in these tables  I want to save the following Details in Third table as

```
Table3
First Name  Varchar
Last  Name  Varchar
Dob         Date
Address     varchar
Email       Varchar
City        Varchar
Country     Varchar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins

```
 INSERT INTO Table3 SELECT t1.First_Name,
t1.Last_Name,
t1.Dob  ,     
t1.Address   ,
t1.Email    , 
t1.City  ,    
t1.Country   
 FROM t1 inner join t2 on t1.dob=t2.dob
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the trick for you:

```
insert into table3
(`first Name`, `last Name`, DOB, Address, Email, City, Country)
values
(select
    t1.`first Name`,
    t1.`last Name`,
    t1.DOB,
    t1.Address,
    t1.Email,
    t1.City,
    t1.Country
from
    `table 1` t1
        join `Table 2` t2
            on t1.DOB=t2.DOB)
```

But you would also do well to read [this article I wrote on SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) that goes into much much more detail that this snippet and tries to explain a lot of the concepts of joins and other functions in detail.

Comment: Are u sure?Iam getting an Sql syntax error in the Select statement in the query.

Comment: Make sure your field names and table names are spelled correctly, and if escaped with a single quote, make sure that they are capitalized correctly.  I am not certain that you gave us the correct table and field names for your example.